# PHP post is appending extra " \" " Why is it so?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using

```
  <textarea id="content" name="content" style="width:0; height:0;">  
<?php  $content = file_get_contents($url);    ?> 
</textarea>
```

and i am posting this text area to a php file

```
$file = $_POST["content"];
echo $file;
```

The output that i am getting displayed Everything with an extra \"

All the images , all the references... Any solution for this ?

Comment: check in php.ini the magic_quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a start, the code in the textarea won't actually output anything, since all it's doing is assigning the contents of `$url` to the `$content` variable. Try using `echo` to output it:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($url) ?>
```

As for the slashes, it sounds like a [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) problem. You can easily check this in the course of a script by calling [`get_magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php), which will return `true` if the feature is enabled. The PHP website has some useful information on [how to disable it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: How do i know is it On or Off on the server ? The php ini which is in my dir contains only one line allow_url_include = On

Comment: Read the links I provided. As I said, `get_magic_quotes_gpc` will return `true` if it's on.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) activated.

You can check this, either in your configuration-files, or by viewing the output of `php_info()`. [Here are instructions on how to disable this "feature".](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Comment: How do i know is it On or Off on the server ?

Comment: The php ini which is in my dir contains only one line  allow_url_include = On